# Parallel Class and CPU

Tags: .net, cpu, parallel.foreach

I've a win-app. It launchs a million of calls to a service using .Net Parallel Class.
When my app and the service are in same server (8cpu, iis 7.5), process is very fast and I see 30-40 threads in IIS (Worked Process list) and a lot of active requests.
But when app and service are in diferent server (4cpu and 8cpu), process goes slow and I see only a worked process listed. I also see two active request in Performance Counters Monitor.

It doesn't a communication problem, it seems like a cpu problem.
How I can get the same time without put my app together the service?

Comment: Try a single request and do the parallel.for in the service.

Comment: Oh and part of the problem could be the 2 connection per client limit in http. You do wcf over http?

Comment: I can't. The service receive a person entity, runs a rules engine and returns a result about that person.

Comment: Googled around, it seems the limit is 16. So that isnt the problem. As you say you cant change the interface, you need a real wcf expert, not me. Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried changing [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx)?

Comment: I added ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit=100 before call to Parallel.ForEach. No changes for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this to my web.config to allow 100 connections for any IP (*)

```
<system.net> 
  <connectionManagement> 
    <add address="*" maxconnection="100" /> 
  </connectionManagement> 
</system.net>
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133738/Quick-Ways-to-Boost-Performance-and-Scalability-of